# MySQL statement to return unique association

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
idStudent  class       day        hour
1          Biology     Monday     10:00 AM
1          Biology     Friday     11:00 AM
1          Chemistry   Monday     09:00 AM
2          Biology     Monday     10:00 AM
2          Chemistry   Friday     09:00 AM
1          Informatics Wednesday  11:00 AM
```

I want to get the following output:

```
idStudent  class       
1          Biology
1          Chemistry
2          Biology
2          Chemistry
1          Informatics
```

What select statement should I use to get that result(only one association between an **idStudent** and a **class**)?
For example, **idStudent** 1 has biology **class** monday and friday, and I want to obtain only the association between an idStudent and a class, **idStudent** *1* and **class** *biology*.
I've tried using **distinct** or **group by**, but in that case I receive only one result for **idStudent** using **distinct** or only the **class** using **group by**.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT idStudent,  class FROM mytable`

Comment: select distinct idStudent, class FROM mytable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use select distinct

```
select distinct idstudent, class
from my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(idstudent,'_',class) FROM my_table` - this will give you what you want I believe.